# FreeBSD - can't find kernel, finds slices but no files on them

Tags: boot, bootloader, freebsd

I have an old FreeBSD 4.7 machine.

When booting, I get to the loader, that says can't find 'kernel'. issuing **lsdev -v** returns the correct layout of the disk, but if I try to read the content of the disk it says can't open '/' no such file or directory. It lists the slices as of FFS type, which is correct.

I can mount all slices in FreeSBIE without any trouble, and there is indeed files on the /-filesystem.

What can I try to do?

Thanks,
Zyber

Comment: You write there are files on `/` when you boot FreeSBIE. Can you check if there is an /boot/kernel or a /boot/kernel.old ?  (That is the location in 7.4, which is the oldest FReeBSD server I have access to.  Note that FreeBSD 4.7 is from mid 2002, that is truly ancient.

Comment: There is a /kernel, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fault was that the FreeSBIE did something that was to new for FreeBSD 4.2.

When using machines running FreeBSD 6.2 it worked as a charm.